# possible embeddings for a $2$-connected planar graph

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness, planar-graphs

When I asked the question "cycles and faces in planar graphs", I learned that the
 numbers of vertices in the faces are not unique, if the planar graph is only $2$-connected.

My question now is : How can I find all possible embeddings (in particular, all possible sizes for the faces) for a given $2$-connected planar graph ?

Is it enough to know the cycles, or do I need more information ?

And finally, is there a straightfort method to construct an arbitary embedding ?